# Mudar body da aplicação inline ReactJS

Tags: javascript, react

Olá, pessoal. Além de mudar o img com o id='pikachu' quando o usuário clicar três vezes no h1PIKACHU eu gostaria de mudar o body da aplicação para a mesma imagem. Alguém poderia me ajudar? O código está assim:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const InfoPokemon = ({ data }) => {
  const [contador, setContador] = useState(0);

  const pokemonImage = contador >= 3 ? `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/dream-world/${data.id}.svg` : 'https://i.imgur.com/ntFjCsD.png'

  return (
    <>
      {
        (!data) ? "" : (
          <>
            {data.name !== 'pikachu' ? (
              <h1>{data.name}</h1>

            ) : (
              <a
                onClick={() => setContador((c) => c + 1)}><h1>PIKACHU</h1></a>

            )}
            {data.name !== 'pikachu' ? (
              <img src={`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/dream-world/${data.id}.svg`} alt="" />

            ) : (
                  <img src={pokemonImage} alt="" id='pikachu' />

            )}

            <div className="habilidades">
              {
                data.abilities.map(poke => {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <div className="grupo">
                        <h2>{poke.ability.name}</h2>
                      </div>
                    </>
                  )
                })
              }
            </div>
            <div className="status">
              {
                data.stats.map(poke => {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <ProgressBar className="containerP" completed={poke.base_stat} customLabel={poke.stat.name} />
                    </>
                  )
                })
              }
            </div>
          </>
        )
      }
    </>
  )
}
export default InfoPokemon;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Da pra fazer isso utilizando um useEffect, que observa o contador, e quando ele passar de 3, muda o background do body, imagino que seja isso:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (contador = 3) {
      document.body.style.background = `url(${pokemonImage}) no-repeat`
    }
  }, [contador])
```

O useEffect, quando contém esse `[contador]` no final, é como se fosse um observador, que indica que esse código dentro (`if(contador>=3){...}`) vai rodar toda vez que o `contador` mudar de valor, então quando você clicar três vezes, ele muda o background do `body` para o `pokemonImage`.

Ai o background do body vai depender de como você quer que fique, então eu botei uma `url(pokemonImage)` e um `no-repeat`, mas isso é css, então tem que ver como melhor encaixar no seu código.

O código final fica assim :

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const InfoPokemon = ({ data }) => {
  const [contador, setContador] = useState(0);

  const pokemonImage = contador >= 3 ? `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/dream-world/${data.id}.svg` : 'https://i.imgur.com/ntFjCsD.png'

  useEffect(() => {
    if (contador = 3) {
      document.body.style.background = `url(${pokemonImage}) no-repeat`
    }
  }, [contador])

  return (
    <>
      {
        (!data) ? "" : (
          <>
            {data.name !== 'pikachu' ? (
              <h1 onClick={() => setContador((c) => c + 1)}>{data.name}</h1>

            ) : (
              <a
                onClick={() => setContador((c) => c + 1)}><h1>PIKACHU</h1></a>

            )}
            {data.name !== 'pikachu' ? (
              <img src={`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/other/dream-world/${data.id}.svg`} alt="" />

            ) : (
              <img src={pokemonImage} alt="" id='pikachu' />

            )}

            <div className="habilidades">
              {
                data.abilities.map(poke => {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <div className="grupo">
                        <h2>{poke.ability.name}</h2>
                      </div>
                    </>
                  )
                })
              }
            </div>
            <div className="status">
              {
                data.stats.map(poke => {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <ProgressBar className="containerP" completed={poke.base_stat} customLabel={poke.stat.name} />
                    </>
                  )
                })
              }
            </div>
          </>
        )
      }
    </>
  )
}
export default InfoPokemon;
```